# Rails: Regex for lastname or firstname in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I know that this question is over asked, but I couldn't find something that fits in my case and also works with rails. I'm looking for a simple regex for words that can contain:

- letters(no digits)
- white spaces
- . (dot) or - (dash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex allows letters, white space, dot and dash:

```
/[a-z\s.-]/i
```

Your validation in model would be:

```
validates_format_of :first_name, :with => /[a-z\s.-]/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Sharvy Ahmed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29322090/10907864).

You can also represent the validation in this format in the model

Define the **Regex** as a constant and then reference it in the `first_name` validation.

```
validates :first_name, format: { with: VALID_NAME_REGEX }

VALID_NAME_REGEX = /[a-z\s.-]/i
```

**Where**:

```
/    - Indicates the start of a new character
a-z  - Matches characters in the range 'a' to 'z'
\s   - Matches any whitespace character like tabs, spaces
.    - Matches a '.' character
-    - Matches a '-' character
/i   - Makes the whole expression case insensitive.
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**